# Is Firebase.ServerValue.increment() not available in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I have used ServerValue.TIMESTAMP but i couldnt use the increment function. I have seen that it is available in [JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) 
but i if i try using it in react it give me an error  'ServerValue.increment(1) is an invalid function'.

I am using firebase real time database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServerValue.increment()` operation is a very recent addition to the Firebase SDKs. It is indeed quite likely that it hasn't been added to the React-Native Firebase implementation yet.

You might want to [file a feature request](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues) for it, or (even better) a pull request.